# Bixby table to capsule template generator doesn't handle Year column as expected

Tags: bixby

I have a table that contains a year column, but the generated model does not seem to be able to search by year as I would expect.

Year model:

```
integer (Year) {
  description (Description for Year)
}
```

Autogenerated js:

```
var dates = require('dates')

  exports.timeToMili = timeToMili

  function timeToMili(time) {
    //TODO consider zone offset
    var timeStr
    if (time instanceof Object && "hour" in time) {
      var hour = ("amPm" in time && String(time.amPM) == 'Pm') ? Number(time.hour) + 12 : Number(time.hour)
      var minute = ("minute" in time && time.minute ? time.minute : "00")
      //sanity check
      timeStr = hour + ":" + (String(minute).length < 2 ? "0" + minute : minute)
      return  dates.ZonedDateTime.parseTime(timeStr, "H:mm").getMillisFromEpoch()
    }
    return null //TODO error handling
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This training worked:

[g:CO2Concentration] Show the CO2 concentration for (1967)[v:Year]

The key was finding that "Year" was the correct Node to select.